# Will careers.stackoverflow.com do anything in particular to attract "smart" companies?

Tags: discussion, jobs

In [podcast #70](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/podcast-70/) Jeff and Joel agree that smart companies should be looking for good programmers not the other way around.

Obviously the more smart companies (*aka "great employment opportunities"*) that sign up and browse the filed CVs the better for all of us good programmers.  On that subject, is there anything specific that can or will be done to attract these smart companies to careers.stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: I also wonder whether or not Fog Creek will hire using SO careers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is one area where we plan to leverage the crap out of Joel's reputation.

In particular you can expect us to approach any and all employers who currently advertise on http://jobs.stackoverflow.com

And if you're angling for a job at Fog Creek, obviously, this is one place where they'll be checking. Though Fog Creek is ridiculously selective, so good luck, and enter "NY, NY" as one of your desired work locations. :)

Comment: Can we assume the Joel Test might be packaged into the Employer side functionality as well?

Comment: How you will market to employers in the UK?  jobs.stackoverflow.com have failed to get many UK companies using it.